# Is it possible to accumulate CSS transitions rather than overwrite them?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm wondering whether there is a way of accumulating CSS transitions rather than overriding them if applied to individual classes. For example, I have two two utility classes `.btn` and `.shadow`, which work fine standalone:

```css
/* .btn utility class */
.btn {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid darkblue;
  color: white;
  background-color: #4fb0e8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  
  transition: background-color 0.8s; /* transition #1 */
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #4f8ce8; /* this should always transition */
  font-size: 15px; /* this should never transition */
}

/* .shadow utility class */
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: box-shadow 0.8s; /* transition #2 */
}

.shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Button 1</button>

<div class="shadow">
  <h2>I div with a shadow</h2>
</div>

<button class="btn shadow">Button 2</button>
```

As you can see, when you hover over the button, its color transitions, and when you hover over the div, its shadow also transitions. This is expected behaviour.

The issue is, when I combine these two classes as shown in the last button labeled Button 2, the background-color transition is overwritten by the box-shadow transition, and so, the background color of the box no longer transitions. Preferably I would be able to somehow "accumulate" the transitions effects for both classes when applied together. Is there an easy way to do this with CSS, or will I have to manually combine and add the shadow transition to my button class?

Comment: no, you cannot combine them in that way. each class that stacks will overwrite the properties of the previous, based on the order they are defined in the CSS (not the order they are written into the class list on the element). If you want both, you would need to create a new class like .btn-shadow which would define something like `transition: box-shadow 0.8s, background-color 0.8s` OR `transition: all 0.8s;`

Answer (score -1):

Change the transition of `.shadow` from `transition: box-shadow 0.8s;` to `transition: box-shadow 0.8s, background-color 0.8s;`